# Could not load dynamic library 'libcupti.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcupti.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

System information

- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 18.04)
- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python version: 3.6
- Installed using virtualenv
- CUDA/cuDNN version: 11.5 / 8.1.0.77
- GPU model and memory: RTX 3090 24GB nvidia driver 460.39
- TensorFlow version: 2.4.0 pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.4.0

Describe the problem

Installed cuda 11.2 and cudnn 8.1.0.77. Faced the following problem when I run train.py

Could not load dynamic library 'libcupti.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcupti.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem

- List lib files on `/usr/local/cuda-11.2/extras/CUPTI/lib64/lib*`

  ```
  $ ls /usr/local/cuda-11.2/extras/CUPTI/lib64/lib*
  ```
- I could not find `libcupti.so.11.0`. Other files should be there such that `libcupti.so`, `libcupti.so.11.2`, ...
- Manage a link between `libcupti.so.11.2` and libcupti.so.11.0 using a comand 'sudo ln -s'

  ```
  $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-11.2/extras/CUPTI/lib64/libcupti.so.11.2 /usr/local/cuda-11.2/extras/CUPTI/lib64/libcupti.so.11.0
  ```
- List lib files on /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcup*

  ```
  ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcup*
  ```
- I could not find `libcupti.so.11.0`. Other files should be there such
  that `libcupti.so`, `libcupti.so,2`, `libcupti.so.10.1`, ...
- Manage a link between `libcupti.so.11.2` and `libcupti.so.11.0` using a comand `sudo ln -s`

  ```
  $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-11.2/extras/CUPTI/lib64/libcupti.so.11.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcupti.so.11.0
  ```

This fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

`pip install transformers[torch]`

or downgrade torch to 2.0.0. Thats work for me.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Cuda-11.3, lib64 folder is removed from /usr/local/cuda-11.2/extras/CUPTI/. All lib files are moved to ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64/ or ls /usr/local/cuda-11.3/lib64/.

- List lib files on /usr/local/cuda/lib64/

  ```
  $ ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcupti*
  ```
- I could not find libcupti.so.11.0. Other files should be there such that libcupti.so, libcupti.so.11.3, ...
- Manage a link between libcupti.so.11.3 and libcupti.so.11.0 using a comand 'sudo ln -s'

  ```
  $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-11.3/lib64/libcupti.so.11.3 /usr/local/cuda-11.3/lib64/libcupti.so.11.0
  ```

That is it. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the paths for binaries and libraries. On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I follow the next steps. First, using `find` command, I search for the path of `nvcc` and `libcublas.so.*`:

```
sudo find / -name 'nvcc'  # Path to binaries
sudo find / -name 'libcublas.so.*'  # Path to libraries
```

Then, add the next lines at the end of file `~/.profile` (or just export the environment variables) according to the paths you found above. In my system, Cuda was installed on `/usr/local/cuda-11.4`.

```
if [ -d "/usr/local/cuda-11.4" ]; then
    export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
fi
```

Restart the computer and try it again.