# Tensorflow unable to find libcupti.so and libcupti.so.11.2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I've been following [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65933294/826983) and created respective symbolic links und `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` for the missing files but I keep getting the warning

> `[.. W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcupti.so.11.2';`

GPU training is working but I am not able to use the Tensorboard/Profiler without this library. On the Tensorboard Profile tab I am greeted by the follwoing error message:

> Failed to load libcupti (is it installed and accessible?)

#### Full log (relevant part)

```
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945508: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:110] Profiler session initializing.
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945528: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:125] Profiler session started.
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945557: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1630] Profiler found 1 GPUs
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945763: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcupti.so.11.2'; dlerror: libcupti.so.11.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945828: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcupti.so'; dlerror: libcupti.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945835: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_error_manager.cc:135] cuptiGetTimestamp: error 999: 
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945844: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_error_manager.cc:184] cuptiSubscribe: ignored due to a previous error.
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945848: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_error_manager.cc:457] cuptiGetResultString: ignored due to a previous error.
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945853: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1682] function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error 
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945869: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:143] Profiler session tear down.
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945881: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_error_manager.cc:140] cuptiFinalize: ignored due to a previous error.
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945884: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_error_manager.cc:457] cuptiGetResultString: ignored due to a previous error.
2022-05-01 11:39:36.945888: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1773] function cupti_interface_->Finalize()failed with error
```

Comment: Could you try to change the file name as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71562539/14290681)? May help you.Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2 I think this is something similar I did but on Windows.